# Does wildcarding significantly hurt BIND Performance?

Tags: wildcards, dns, bind

I have enabled RPZ on my BIND 9.9.4 DNS server and I wanted to be able to wildcard some records in my RPZ zone, but I am afraid of the performance hit this might cause. Does anyone out there have some sage advice for me?

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't hurt performance. A wildcard is a single resource record. It doesn't take any more or less system resources than any other single resource record.